# Applying theorem to gambler coin toss problem (Norris , Markov Chain exercise 1.3.2)

Tags: probability, solution-verification, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, markov-process

This's the problem I'm facing (from Norris , Markov Chain p.18) :
" A gambler has £2 and needs to increase it to £10 in a hurry. He can play a game with the following rules: a fair coin is tossed; if a player bets on the right side, he wins a sum equal to his stake, and his stake is returned; otherwise he loses his stake. The gambler decides to use a bold strategy in which he stakes all his money if he has £5 or less, and otherwise stakes just enough to increase his capital, if he wins, to £10.
Let $X_0$ = 2 and let $X_n$ be his capital after n throws. **Prove that the gambler will achieve his aim with probability 1/5.**"

I've seen other approaches to this question , but the same book provided a theorem and I want see if it is applicable here , the theorem states : (when markov property is satisfied ) The vector of hitting probabilities [on a set A $\subset$ the state space I] $h^A = \; (h_i^A : i \in I)$ is the minimal non-negative solution to the system of linear equations
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
h_i^A = 1 & for \; i \in A \\
h_i^A = \sum_{j\in I} p_{ij}h_j^A & for \; i \notin A 
\end{array}\right.
$$
where

- $p_{ij}$ is conditional transition probability from state i to j
- you may take  $h_i^A = P_i(hit\;A)$ , interpreted as : starting at state i , the probability  of the random variable assuming a value in A in finite time

A proof of this theorem is given in the book p.13 .

I tried to apply this theorem to the above problem  : The process $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ where n is integral time  assumes value in state space $\{0,...,10\}$ . Denote hitting probability starting at state i as $h_{i}^{\{10\}}$ .
I think the "probability 1/5" is $h_2^{\{10\}}$ . Using information provided to define
$$ 
\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
h_0^{\{10\}} = 0 \\ 
h_{10}^{\{10\}} = 1 \\
h_{i}^{\{10\}} = \frac{1}{2} h_{2i}^{\{10\}} + \frac{1}{2} h_{0}^{\{10\}} \quad   i = 1,...,5 \\
h_{i}^{\{10\}} = \frac{1}{2} h_{10}^{\{10\}} + \frac{1}{2} h_{2i-10}^{\{10\}} \quad i = 6,...,10 \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
But I couldn't solve for  $h_{2}^{\{10\}} $ , is the theorem applicable here ?

Comment: These equations are correct.  There are four equations relating $h_2,h_4,h_6$ and $h_8$.  Maybe the subscripts and superscripts are getting in the way, so call the numbers a,b,c and d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring superscript . There are four equations relating $ℎ_2,ℎ_4,ℎ_6 \; and \; ℎ_8$ ,
$$ h_2 = .5h_4  $$
$$  h_4 = .5h_8  $$
$$ h_6 = .5 + .5h_2 $$
$$ h_8 = .5 + .5 h_6 $$
which gives
$$ h_2 = .5(.5(.5+.5(.5+.5h_2))) $$
$$ h_2 = 1/5$$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the gambler's fortune at time $n$ is a martingale, as he wins or loses the same amount with equal probability. We can do this on general state space $ \{ 0, 1,2, \dotsc, N \} $. We have
\begin{equation*}
i = \sum_{j = 0}^{N} p_{ij} j 
\end{equation*}
for all $ i $. Then, for any $ n \geq 1 $,
\begin{equation*}
i = \sum_{j = 0}^{N} p_{ij}^{(n)} j .
\end{equation*}
Now, taking limit as $n \to \infty $, and noting that $ p_{ij}^{(n)} \to 0 $ for $ i =1,2, \dotsc, N-1 $ and $ p_{iN}^{(n)} \to h_i $ where $ h(i) $ is absorption probability at $N$. Thus, we get
\begin{equation*}
i = N h_i \implies h_i = \frac{i}{N}. 
\end{equation*}
In this particular case, $ i = 2 $ and $ N = 10 $ so that $ h_2 = 1/5 $.